# D3JS with Kibana

Tags: javascript, d3.js, kibana

Is it possible to host a D3.js control inside kibana 
So for example if I click  a cell in a row in kibana it should run a D3.js Background .Will it require a change in the Kibana source code ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [it is possible](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/05/20/advanced-kibana-dashboard/): though integration within an existing dashboard may not be trivial. From the linked article:

> As I understand, you want to access your custom script dashboard. If
>   so, keep your script file (.js) directly under app/dashboards and
>   access that http://localhost/kibana/#/dashboard/script/.js